# Manipulate JSON input to produce a JSON list of items

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-step-functions

I am trying to find a way to manipulate my input JSON so that I can pass it to a map function which would call another step function for processing.

My input JSON looks like this:

```
  "notificationType": "Received",
  "mail": {
    "timestamp": "2023-05-31",
    "source": "source@gmail.com",
    "messageId": "xyz",
    "destination": [
      "email1",
      "email2"
    ],
    "headersTruncated": false,
    "headers": [...],
    "commonHeaders": {
      ....
    }
}
```

I would like to produce a JSON that would look like this:

```
[{
  "email_address": "email1"
  "notificationType": "Received",
  "mail": {
    "timestamp": "2023-05-31T16:24:48.413Z",
    "source": "source@gmail.com",
    "messageId": "xyz",
    "destination": [
      "email1",
      "email2"
    ],
    "headersTruncated": false,
    "headers": [...],
    "commonHeaders": {
      ....
    }
},
{
  "email_address": "email2"
  "notificationType": "Received",
  "mail": {
    "timestamp": "2023-05-31T16:24:48.413Z",
    "source": "source@gmail.com",
    "messageId": "xyz",
    "destination": [
      "email1",
      "email2"
    ],
    "headersTruncated": false,
    "headers": [...],
    "commonHeaders": {
      ....
    }
}]
```

This list would be passed to a map step which would execute another step function.
Or if there is any way to pass original input to a Map along with $.mail.destination list that would also work, but I couldn't find a way to do that either.

Couldn't find anything in AWS built in functions to manipulate json in such a way

Comment: A few questions: What are you trying to achieve? When you say pass to a map function, what does that mean? You have to have some compute like a Lambda function in order to manipulate the JSON and trigger a step function based on this.

Comment: Sorry, probably didn't phrase it very well.. @Justin Callison described what I was trying to do very well...

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you have an single JSON object as input. That object contains an array of items called `destination`. You want to use this to create an array of items, one for each destination, that also includes some of the data from original object as context.

If so, I'd use a [Map](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/amazon-states-language-map-state.html) state to do this. See the [Amazon State Language](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/concepts-states.html) (ASL) below to illustrate. This uses an Map state with your `destination` array as the `ItemsPath` which means you will have one iteration per `destination`. It also uses `ItemSelector` to shape the input to each of the iterations to include common data from the original input. It then uses `Parameters` in a [Pass State](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/amazon-states-language-pass-state.html) to shape the item as you specified.

```
{
  "StartAt": "Generate Input",
  "States": {
    "Generate Input": {
      "Type": "Pass",
      "Result": {
        "notificationType": "Received",
        "mail": {
          "timestamp": "2023-05-31",
          "source": "source@gmail.com",
          "messageId": "xyz",
          "destination": [
            "email1",
            "email2"
          ],
          "headersTruncated": false,
          "headers": [
            "header1",
            "header2",
            "header3"
          ],
          "commonHeaders": {
            "commonHeader1": "value1",
            "commonHeader2": "value2",
            "commonHeader3": "value3"
          }
        }
      },
      "Next": "Map"
    },
    "Map": {
      "Type": "Map",
      "ItemProcessor": {
        "ProcessorConfig": {
          "Mode": "INLINE"
        },
        "StartAt": "Shape Item",
        "States": {
          "Shape Item": {
            "Type": "Pass",
            "End": true,
            "Parameters": {
              "email_address.$": "$.itemValue",
              "notificationType.$": "$.originalInput.notificationType",
              "mail.$": "$.originalInput.mail"
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "End": true,
      "ItemsPath": "$.mail.destination",
      "ItemSelector": {
        "originalInput.$": "$",
        "itemValue.$": "$$.Map.Item.Value"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This will then yield the following result, which I think is what you wanted. You could then pass this into another Map state. Or this might allow you to just add your processing logic after the Pass state in the `ItemProcessor` defined above.

```
[
  {
    "email_address": "email1",
    "mail": {
      "timestamp": "2023-05-31",
      "source": "source@gmail.com",
      "messageId": "xyz",
      "destination": [
        "email1",
        "email2"
      ],
      "headersTruncated": false,
      "headers": [
        "header1",
        "header2",
        "header3"
      ],
      "commonHeaders": {
        "commonHeader1": "value1",
        "commonHeader2": "value2",
        "commonHeader3": "value3"
      }
    },
    "notificationType": "Received"
  },
  {
    "email_address": "email2",
    "mail": {
      "timestamp": "2023-05-31",
      "source": "source@gmail.com",
      "messageId": "xyz",
      "destination": [
        "email1",
        "email2"
      ],
      "headersTruncated": false,
      "headers": [
        "header1",
        "header2",
        "header3"
      ],
      "commonHeaders": {
        "commonHeader1": "value1",
        "commonHeader2": "value2",
        "commonHeader3": "value3"
      }
    },
    "notificationType": "Received"
  }
]
```

Comment: Thank yo so much... I could not figure out the right way to use parameters and I didn't know you can access original input via $.originalInput.. That's what I've been missing... I've been trying to manipulate outputPath. Thanks!

Comment: Nice! Glad I could help. Keep in mind that it's really the ItemSelector that's the trick here. It allows you to shape the input to a Map iteration. In my example $.originalInput was available in the pass state because of what I did in ItemSelector. But I could have called that key anything and $.originalnput isn't special. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/input-output-itemselector.html

Comment: Yes, I got that now. I thought that input would be passed down with ResultPath to the next task like with other task, s.a. Pass or Lambda, but here we need to use ItemSelector to preserve the original input.